# How to sanitize ajax post data in php?

Tags: php

I have a textfield I would like to sanitize. The data from the textfield is sent with ajax post to a php file. I would like to sanitize this string in the php file before I write it to a mysql database.

My problem is (as I understand it) that I cannot call any sanitizing functions in that php file because it is being called by ajax so those functions are not available. Is this correct? If so how can you sanitize this data?

Example of php file called by ajax with sanitizing functions...

```
function sanitizeString($string)
{
    $string = strip_tags($string);  //I cannot access these functions because the file was called by ajax
    $string = htmlentities($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
}
$group_id = sanitizeString($_POST['userid']);
$textbox_value = sanitizeString($_POST['title_text']);
//Write these values to mysql database...

//DOES NOT WORK
$group_id = sanitizeString($_POST['userid']);
$textbox_value = sanitizeString($_POST['title_text']);

//replacing above with this does work (and commenting out function)
$group_id = $_POST['userid'];
$textbox_value = $_POST['title_text'];
```

Comment: If you assign to `Element.textContent` or `Element.value`, in JavaScript, the tags won't be viewed as markup, and you won't have to worry about them, so don't even strip them.

Comment: There's no difference in PHP when it's called by AJAX.

Comment: This is not a mysql or ajax or javascript question. Please remove those tags.

Comment: What makes you think you can't access those functions?

Comment: hmmm OK, thanks for your replies. I guess there must be an error in the above code then because the mysql query works fine without the above code, but when I add that it no longer writes anything to my database.

Comment: Just make sure you are using prepared statements.

Comment: @Barmar updated to show what successfully writes to database vs not writing anything

Comment: You have no `return $string;` statement in the function.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you that fixed it! :D Very grateful for your help.